# In hydraulic fracturing, can total oil/gas production be broken down by stage?

Tags: fracking

I have a hydraulic fracturing data set with some wells and each well is broken up into stages. My response is total well production and my goal is to be able to predict this total well production. The number of wells is extremely low (<10) for any prediction task though but there are many stages per well and each stage has a rich feature set. To synthetically increase my number of observations I want to try to derive a per stage production that is a little smarter than simply dividing the total well production by number of stages. I am thinking of using Gibbs Sampling to produce observations of stage production using the total well production and stage features as givens and a mild assumption of what the covariance matrix would look like. I am wondering from a hydraulic fracturing perspective if it makes sense to think of the total production being a sum of the individual stages?

For reference I am thinking of multiple stages in terms of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bABA8WkxG04

Comment: Petroleum engineers go to college for 4 years to learn how to make these educated guesses. I don't think a paragraph here is going to cover it.

Comment: This isn't really about earth science; it's an engineering question that is better answered in [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother trying to isolate production by stage unless you have a production survey.  Even then it is often irrelevant as the chance of restimulating the specific rock that is lower producing is small.